# PHP image creation functions question

Tags: php

Can someone list all the image creation functions for php?

Comment: Look at http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php

Comment: @oneall Someone downvoted it.

Comment: @oneall it wasn't me that down voted, but I can see why. Have you done any research at all? For such a general question try asking [Google](http://www.google.com.au/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=image+creation+functions+for+php) first. You are pretty much asking someone to copy a list from the PHP documentation and paste it here.

Comment: @alex obviously someone dv it and google is not always the answer thats why there is SO.

Comment: @oneall Not always but it is pretty good for this type of question.

Comment: Google isn't always the answer, but this is a situation where it clearly should've been a first step.

Comment: It's a -1 because the answer is obviously "Yes." Of course somebody can list all the image creation functions in PHP because there are a finite number of them. Why do you need to know if somebody can do that?

Comment: A better question might have been asking why a user should use one particular image creation method instead of another, given a certain situation. You could have described the situation and then named the functions that you are considering. (And even ask if there's a better one that you haven't thought of.)

Answer (score 1):

look at https://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.utilspec.image.php

Answer (score -1):

**Code to create a 200*200 square :**

```
<?php
create_image();
print "<img src=image.png?".date("U").">";

function  create_image(){
        $im = @imagecreate(200, 200) or die("Cannot Initialize new GD image stream");
        $background_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 0);  // yellow
        imagepng($im,"image.png");
        imagedestroy($im);
}
?>
```

**Drawing lines:**

```
<?php
create_image();
print "<img src=image.png?".date("U").">";

function  create_image(){
        $im = @imagecreate(200, 200) or die("Cannot Initialize new GD image stream");
        $background_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 0);   // yellow

        $red = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 0, 0);                  // red
        $blue = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 255);                 // blue
        imageline ($im,   5,  5, 195, 5, $red);
        imageline ($im,   5,  5, 195, 195, $blue); 

        imagepng($im,"image.png");
        imagedestroy($im);
}
?>
```

Comment: who did a downvote? please specify the reason atleast.

Comment: I did **not** down vote your answer, but I would hazard guess it was because it did not address the question in full but provided a couple of select examples.